# pagingtoolbar does not receive total number

Tags: json, extjs4.1

Hi I have a grid in extjs4, where I need paging, the server sends correctly the totalProperty, but the pagingToolbar sees only the number of received records, not the total number, so in example if I limit the number of records to 200 and the pageSize of the store is 50 it is possible to move over the four pages, but I lose the other 1800 records that I left in the db;
this is my store:

```
 var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    pageSize: 50,
    model: 'companiesModel',
    autoLoad: true,
    root:'results',

    listeners :
    {
        load : function(store)
        {// riporta il numero di items nello store in alto sulla grid
            Ext.getCmp('numRow').setText("Companies: "+store.getCount());
        }
    },
    proxy: {
        idProperty: 'id',
        type: 'direct',
        directFn: QueryDatabase.getResults,
        totalProperty:'total',
        api:{
            read:QueryDatabase.getResults,
            update:QueryDatabase.updateCompany
        }


    }
});
```

this is the pagingtoolbar put as dockeditem ofthe grid:

```
dockedItems: [Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Paging', {
        dock: 'bottom',
    pageSize:50,
        store: store,
    displayInfo: true,
        displayMsg: 'Displaying Companies {0} - {1} of {2}',
    emptyMsg: "No Companies to display"
    })]
```

this is part of my json as it is shown by firebug:

```
total
```

2026

result

[Object { noteid=

"1811"

,  address=

"Not Associated"

,  city=

"Not Associated"

,  altri elementi...}, Object { noteid=

"4956"

,  address=

"x"

,  city=

"Buenos Aires"

,  altri elementi...}, Object { noteid=

"4957"

,  address=

"x"

,  city=

"Buenos Aires"

,  altri elementi...}, 47 altri elementi...]

I googled a lot without any success, i could not find my mistake, I am sure that paging should not be so difficult, thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 1):

I solved, I changed  the json send by my server as descripted in 
[extjs 4, direct php proxy and grid paging](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?211181-extjs-4-direct-php-proxy-and-grid-paging)
I put the total together with the data

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the [`startParam`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-cfg-startParam), [`limitParam`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-cfg-limitParam), and/or [`pageParam`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-cfg-pageParam) configs are set up properly on the proxy as per your server api requirements. If so, your server-side code is not correctly processing the request for subsequent pages. Check the request details and response in firebug as each page is requested via the toolbar.

Further, the [`totalProperty`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-cfg-totalProperty) and [`root`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json-property-root) configs go on the reader:

```
proxy: {
    ...
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'results',
        totalProperty: 'total'
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response,I think  my proxy now should be  ok , I changed as you said, I set startParam:'start',
   limitParam:'limit',
   pageParam:'page', but as before, the pagingtoolbar does not use the totalproperty and not let me to move on the pages I can see only page 1 of 1